# modifying PrintDescribeMacro of doc.sty

Tags: programming, dtx

I would like to redefine the command `PrintDescribeMacro`of `doc.sty`
in order to create a label that I can link to using hyperref.

However whenever I add a label to the command I get an error

```
\ifcsdef{PrintDescribeMacro}
   {\def\PrintDescribeMacro#1{%
   \label{doc:desc:#1}%
   \strut \MacroFont %
   \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames} \string #1\ }}{}
```

because the label is created with a different content than what I expect

```
\newlabel{doc:desc:\unhbox \voidb@x \relax \begingroup \catcode `\spacefactor 
\@m 11\relax \par }{{1}{3}{Commands provided by doc.sty and ltxdoc}{MacroName.1}{}}
```

Any better idea how to modify the commands of doc.sty?

Comment: I know this is an old question; did you make any progress? If so, please add your solution. Or make a minimal example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have created a sty file called doctools (see https://code.google.com/p/latexthesistemplate/source/browse/trunk/packages/publish/doctools.dtx) which defines this command without the label. So no, there was no progress.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow for the fact that `#1` here is a command, and so when it gets written to the `.aux` file it may expand. You could use `\string`, but you'd still have an issue when reading back the command. A simplistic approach is to turn into a string and then gobble the `\`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\PrintDescribeMacro}[1]{%
 \label{doc:desc:\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}%
 \strut
 \MacroFont
 \color{red}%
 \string #1\ %
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{\foo}
\end{document}
```

Note that this may go wrong if you pass something other than a command name here (say a single active char): I guess a fuller fix would include a test for this.